# HEVC Content on PS4 Games?

Tags: ps4, graphics-card

I am wondering if anyone is aware, or if it is even possible to determine, if PS4 games discs include HEVC encoded video (e.g., cutscenes or otherwise). I realize that most 4K content is rendered on the fly by the console’s graphics engine, but am curious if any 4K (or non-4K) video comes with the discs.

Answer (score 3):

No, because the PS4 does not support HEVC (aka H.265).

According to [the official user's guide](https://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/music/mp_format_m.html), the supported video formats are:

> - MKV
>
>   - Video: H.264/MPEG-4 AVC High Profile Level 4.2
>   - Audio: MP3, AAC LC, AC-3 (Dolby Digital)
> - AVI
>
>   - Video: MPEG4 ASP, H.264/MPEG-4 AVC High Profile Level 4.2
>   - Audio: MP3, AAC LC, AC-3 (Dolby Digital)
> - MP4
>
>   - Video: H.264/MPEG-4 AVC High Profile Level 4.2, H.264/MPEG-4 AVC High Profile Level 5.2 (PlayStation®4 Pro only)
>   - Audio: AAC LC, AC-3 (Dolby Digital), LPCM
> - MPEG-2 PS
>
>   - Video: MPEG2 Visual
>   - Audio: MP2 (MPEG2 Audio Layer 2), MP3, AAC LC, AC-3 (Dolby Digital), LPCM
> - MPEG-2 TS
>
>   - Video: H.264/MPEG-4 AVC High Profile Level 4.2, MPEG2 Visual
>   - Audio: MP2 (MPEG2 Audio Layer 2), AAC LC, AC-3 (Dolby Digital)
> - AVCHD (.m2ts, .mts)
> - XAVC S™ (.mp4)

As you can see, there is no mention of HEVC or H.265, not even for the PS4 Pro.

While it is technically possible for a game to include its own HEVC decoder, it's unlikely any developer would put in the effort to port a video decoder to a console that already ships with a number of decoders of its own.

If size is an issue, it's more efficient to let the console render cutscenes on its own. And if in-engine cutscenes are not an option, a day-one patch that includes the 4k videos could easily be downloaded while the game is running. Distributing the 4k videos as a free DLC is also a viable option.